# How can a \gls entry in the text be appended by the specific glossary entry page number?

Tags: cross-referencing, glossaries

How can one refer in the main text to a glossary name followed by the exact page number of the glossary entry, i.e. instead of just:

> See `\gls{<label>}`

which of course works
something like:

> See `\gls{<label>}` on page `\pagenumber{<label>}`

However `\pageref{<label>}` always returns `??` for a glossary entry label. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: The label used with `gls` is no label which can be handled over to `\pageref` -- `\gls` is like `\ref` -- getting a label value but not setting one (effectively). In addition, this wouldn't be unique, since you could use `\gls{foo}` on another page --> which page should then be referred too?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial solution -- it works for the first use of `\gls{foo}` label only, later calls with the same label are 'ignored' or do nothing.

`glossaries` does indeed define a `glsentry-foo` label when `\gls{foo}` is used -- but this refers to the location of `foo` in the glossary, not on the calling page.

I've grabbed a little bit of `xparse` etc. and other `expl3` code and 'redefined' `gls` to add automatically an additional label `glscall:foo`, which can be referred to with `\pageref{glscall:foo}` then.

Please note that `\gls*` still works as usual, I did not touch that (so far)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newcounter{someglscallcounter}

\makeatletter

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_glslabel_seq
\LetLtxMacro\orig@gls\gls
\RenewDocumentCommand{\gls}{omo}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \IfValueTF{#3}{%
      \orig@gls[#1]{#2}[#3]%
    }{%
      \orig@gls[#1]{#2}
    }%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#3}{%
      \orig@gls{#2}[#3]%
    }{%
      \orig@gls{#2}
    }% 
  }%
  \seq_if_in:NnTF{\g_glslabel_seq}{glscall:#2}{%
    % The label is already used, do nothing. 
  }{%
    \seq_gput_left:Nn{\g_glslabel_seq}{glscall:#2}%
    \typeout{Adding glscall:#2}
    \refstepcounter{someglscallcounter}%
    \label{glscall:#2}%
  }%
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother


\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{duck}{%
name={Duck},
description={Ducks are great}
}

\newglossaryentry{cat}{%
name={Cat},
description={cats are great too}
}



\newglossaryentry{Elephant}{%
name={Elephant},
description={Elephants are huge!}
}

\begin{document}
A \gls{cat} is a cute animal.

A \gls{duck} is a quacking animal 

\gls{Elephant} and \gls{cat} are mammals. 

The entry for  \gls{duck} is on page \pageref{glsentry-duck} but it was used the first time on page \pageref{glscall:duck}

\clearpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the `expl3` experts: I know, I can drop the `%` characters :D

Answer (score 2):

The `glossaries` package has an option `entrycounter`, which defines and uses a counter to automatically number each entry in the glossary. This uses `\refstepcounter` to increment the counter and automatically adds a label, which means that with this option you can reference the label using `\pageref`.

You can prevent the number from appearing in the glossary by redefining `\glsentrycounterlabel` to do nothing, but the counter will still be incremented and labelled. The argument of `\label` isn't simply the glossary label, but is constructed from it with a prefix. The simplest method is to use the extension package `glossaries-extra`, which provides `\glsxtrpageref` for easy use.

The example below uses dummy entries defined in `example-glossaries-brief.tex`, which is provided with the `glossaries` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[entrycounter]{glossaries-extra}

\renewcommand{\glsentrycounterlabel}{}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}
\glsaddall % add all to pad the glossary to two pages.

\begin{document}
See \gls{lorem} on page \glsxtrpageref{lorem}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: See lorem on page 2.]

(Build process: `latex`, `makeglossaries`, `latex`, `latex`)

If you don't want to use `glossaries-extra` (or your version is too old to provide `\glsxtrpageref`), then you can simply do:

```
See \gls{lorem} on page \pageref{glsentry-lorem}.
```

Note that this method only works with glossary styles that use `\glsentryitem` (which all the predefined styles use).